# Scan out a folder + subfolder + get the files with a specific extension in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file-listing

I have a folder named LOGFILES with a subfolder named LOGFILES_OLD.

[image]

But we need to assume that I don't know the contents of the folder.

What I'm trying to develop in PowerShell is a method to show a list of all files with a `.log` extension.

I have failed to get it with something I have found here:

```
Get-Item C:\LOGFILES -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".log"} | Format-List
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use :

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\LOGFILES"  -include *.log -Recurse
```

Comment: It doesn't retrieve the files in one result

Comment: Be carreful its `Get-ChildItem` not `Get-Item`. It works for me with `-Recurse` flag.